# How to pass a string and call it as a class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.reflection

I am a newbie in c# and I am trying to create forms dynamically inside a MdiContainer through a method, by passing the name of the child form class name, in a string. The problem is calling that string as a class.

```
public partial class frmHome : Form
    {
        public frmHome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Method to show a child form
        public void CreateForm(string formName)
        {
            
            //somehow get the type of the class name passed through formName
            Type protoclass = Type.GetType("BackOffice." + formName);
            
            Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(protoclass);

            //Before opening a form close all forms opened
            foreach (Form frmChild in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                frmChild.Close();
            }

            //Open form
            protoClass frm = new protoClass(); //Here, I don't know how to call it.

            //frmHome as Parent
            frm.MdiParent = this;

            //show form
            frm.Show();
        }

        private void loginToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Pass the class name as a string
           createForm(frmLoginAdmin);
        }
```

Comment: If the name of the class was correct your form instance is in obj. JUst cast obj to form and call show on it.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
protoClass frm = new protoClass();
```

with this:

```
Form frm = (Form)obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic-ise it as `CreateForm<T>() where T : Form` then you can just create a new form with `new T()`